# Linq Order by alphabetical

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I got a product table and want to get datas sort by alphabetical. But when i write this query they are still coming by id. I check a lot of page in google but cant find any source.

```
var product = Db.tablename
                .Where(s => s.colum == DropDownList2.SelectedValue)
                .OrderBy(s=> s.Name);
```

Comment: where you use the result of product? I mean are you trying to bind your data to a gridview or to another control? Could you please post also this code? thanks !

Comment: Yes i send restul to datalist.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This query

```
var product = Db.tablename
                .Where(s => s.colum == DropDownList2.SelectedValue)
                .OrderBy(s=> s.Name);
```

will not be executed until it is asked to. So you have to change it to the following one:

```
var product = Db.tablename
                .Where(s => s.colum == DropDownList2.SelectedValue)
                .OrderBy(s=> s.Name).ToList();
```

The reason why that happens is that actually you just have declared a query. I mean you haven't executed it. That's the nature of LINQ queries, which in technical terms is called deffered execution. On the other hand if you call the `ToList()` method at the end of your query, you will trigger the immediate execution of this query and it's result will be a `List` of the same type with `s.Name`.

Comment: I m gettin this error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator

Comment: change the type to nvarchar in your database. That will not affect your data and it will solve your problem. I didn't know anything about this error, but having done a little googling I found this http://forums.asp.net/t/1481629.aspx?Help+Again, which states the above suggestion.

Comment: Colom type was text i changed it varchar max and added ToList(). It s work great :) Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You must use ToList to execute the sort.

```
var product = Db.tablename
                .Where(s => s.colum == DropDownList2.SelectedValue)
                .OrderBy(s=> s.Name).ToList();
```

The order by does nothing, just executes the query, the ToList will do the sort for the original query.

Comment: I m gettin this error

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: Wich Sql version are you using? There's some limitations for older versions of SQL that can cause this error

Comment: Host company using Mssql2012 :/